# Angular 6.1 second @Input not recognized

Tags: angular, input

When I used only 1 @Input (see ElementType below), everything is fine.
But when I add a second @Input (Validation hint), the first input is recognized, but the second one is not.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sh-workspace-header',
  templateUrl: './workspace-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workspace-header.component.scss']
})
export class WorkspaceHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() ElementType: string;
  @Input() ValidationHint: string;  <- Not recognized
  @Output() HeaderEvent = new EventEmitter<WorkspaceHeaderEvent>();
```

The HTML referencing this component:

```
  <div class="heading">
    <sh-workspace-header [ElementType]="'Project'" 
                         [ValidationHint]="'none'" 
                         (HeaderEvent)="catchHeaderEvent($event)" >
    </sh-workspace-header>
  </div>
```

Chrome Dev Tools Console:

[image]

Comment: Did you save the WorkspaceHeaderComponent file ?

Comment: can you recreate this on stackblitz?

Comment: have you added this component in any module?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a string. you can pass normal attribute instead of attribute binding by removing square bracket.

```
<sh-workspace-header ElementType="'Project'" ValidationHint="'none'" (HeaderEvent)="catchHeaderEvent($event)" >
</sh-workspace-header>
```